# Add cookie with multiple values using OWIN ResponseCookieCollection class

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, owin

I need to use the OWIN API to set a cookie that has multiple values.

This can be done using the `HttpCookie` class as follows:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
cookie ["CustomField1"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(customValue1);
cookie ["CustomField2"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(customValue2);
this._httpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

How I can instead create this cookie using the OWIN `ResponseCookieCollection`  class?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.responsecookiecollection(v=vs.113).aspx

This class has an `Append` method for adding a new cookie and value, however it isn't clear how to add a cookie with multiple values. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `collection.Append("MyCookie", $"CustomField1={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(customValue1)}&CustomField2={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(customValue2)}");`

Comment: Thanks @Romoku for your response. I think your example results in a cookie with a single value.  When viewing the cookie in the Headers tab in Fiddler, it appears on a single line, whereas the cookie created using `HttpCookie` class is displayed in Fiddler with each value on a separate line. Perhaps it's because using `ResponseCookieCollection` class results in url encoding of the equals and ampersand characters, but I can't see any option to prevent it from being url encoded.

Comment: Looks like `ResponseCookieCollection` is encoding the values. You can write directly to the headers if you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the `ResponseCookieCollection` class encodes values in the `Append` method.

This can be worked around by adding the multi valued cookies directly to the `IHeaderDictionary`.

Code:

```
public static class HeaderExtensions
{
    public static void SetMultiValuedCookie(
        this IHeaderDictionary headers,
        string key,
        params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] values)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
        }

        if (values == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));
        }

        if (0 >= values.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(values));
        }

        var value = string.Join("&", values.Select(v => $"{Uri.EscapeDataString(v.Key)}={Uri.EscapeDataString(v.Value)}"));

        headers.AppendValues("Set-Cookie", Uri.EscapeDataString(key) + "=" + value + "; path=/");
    }
}
```

Test:

```
var headers = new HeaderDictionary(new Dictionary<string, string[]>());

var values = new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CustomField1", "1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CustomField2", "2"),
};

headers.SetMultiValuedCookie("MyCookie", values);
headers.SetMultiValuedCookie("MyCookie2", values);
```

Result:

[image: HeaderDictionary]

Comment: Thank you so much! Works a treat!